# Reusing public/private keys

Tags: https, openssl, intranet

I am writing a program that is meant to be used over a local wifi network. With the intention of providing some security, I am considering to have devices connect over local https. Is it considered to be common practice to generate one self signed key pair using openssl, then distribute a software package that uses that exact same private and public key?

Answer (score 0):

I would say no, because the key can be extracted from the software package, and the data can be decrypted.

You should generate a key after installing the package, so that it would be unique to the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Private key must be used only by person who created it. If you distribute private key to any other side it becomes compromised and you can't guarantee any security with utilizing this key.

So the answer is: you should generate key pair on each client and distribute only public keys. And even in this case you should understand that there is a risk of "man-in-the-middle" attack.

Comment: So how should I go about generating a new key every time? Should I include openssl in the installation file?

Comment: The best way is making script that generates key pair and sends public key to server by one click. As far as I know OpenSSL license allow you to redistribute it without restrictions. So answer is yes. You should include openssl distrib in software and make script that generates key pair and sends public key to server.